# Weird IE9 Bug with UL and hovered images in CSS

Tags: css, image, hover, internet-explorer-9

I'm working on making a simple navigation box on the right side of a page. I basically have five image-links in a UL that have a hover property in the CSS that sets the background-position so there is the hover effect.

It works fine in Firefox, Safari, Chrome AND IE7. However, fire up IE9 and all of the images have extra vertical margin spacing or something below them by about 1px and when you hover the placement is off by 1px or 2px.

First of all I disabled the automatic IE9 compatibility view by having:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9" />
```

For some reason compatibility view was being turned on by IE9 which messed up my element floating.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="right">
    <ul id="greenpractices">
        <li id="rightmission_water"><a href="water.html">Water</a></li>
        <li id="rightmission_air"><a href="air.html">Air</a></li>
        <li id="rightmission_innovation"><a href="innovation.html">Innovation</a></li>
        <li id="rightmission_energy"><a href="energy.html">Energy</a></li>
        <li id="rightmission_design"><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#right {
float: left;
display: inline;
width: 286px;
border-top: 1px solid #686868;
padding: 17px 16px 0px 17px;
}

ul#greenpractices {
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
width: 286px;
height: 260px;
}

ul#greenpractices li, ul#greenpractices li a, ul#greenpractices li a:active, ul#greenpractices li a:visited {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 286px;
height: 52px;
text-indent: -99999px;
}

ul#greenpractices li a:hover {
background-position: 0 0;
}

li#rightinnovation_innovation a {
background: url('images/rightinnovation_innovation.jpg') bottom;
}

li#rightinnovation_air a {
background: url('images/rightinnovation_air.jpg') bottom;
}

li#rightinnovation_water a {
background: url('images/rightinnovation_water.jpg') bottom;
}

li#rightinnovation_energy a {
background: url('images/rightinnovation_energy.jpg') bottom;
}

li#rightinnovation_design a {
background: url('images/rightinnovation_design.jpg') bottom;
}
```

Many thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Dont get you. Looks exactly the same in IE9 and FF5.01 on Windows 7?

Comment: Do you see the navigation box on the right? The images have margins in between vertically and shift when you hover. I only want the text on the image to change to be brighter when you hover.

Comment: I'm seeing no change between IE9 and Chrome and when I hover in IE, it doesn't display any different.  You might want to change the background image and the hover to the li element instead of the anchor tag.  Sometimes styling on anchor tags just doesn't work as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could it just be the computer I'm using? See above for added screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up figuring out that the IE9 window I was using was zoomed in 105%. Just enough to be unnoticeable. Thanks to everyone who helped - that was frustrating!